# Equation to find a point perpendicular with from an angle

Tags: trigonometry, triangles

Working on a fun side project and I have not done this math in a long time.  Sorry the angle on the diagram is not very accurate.  $d1 = d1$ angle,  In the second diagram a1 = a1 angle.

[image]

[image]

I am trying to figure out an equation or steps for an equation (will be programming these in JavaScript).

Knowing only $P1, P2$ and $P3$,  I need to find the $x,y$ coordinates of $P4$.

So far I have $d1 = \arctan\left(\frac{m2 - m1}{1 + m1*m2} \right)$

And I am now stuck trying to get $P4$ now.  It has been a long time since I did equations like this and blanking on moving them around as needed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $s_{ij}$ denote the distance from $P_i$ to $P_j$.

The unit direction vector from $P_2$ to $P_3$ is
$$ \vec{v}_{23}=\left\langle\frac{x_3-x_2}{s_{23}},\frac{y_3-y_2}{s_{23}}\right\rangle$$
where $s_{23}=\sqrt{(x_3-x_2)^2+(y_3-y_2)^2}$ the distance from $P_2$ to $P_3$.

Since $\vec{P_3P_4}\perp\vec{P_2P_3}$ the unit vector from $P_3$ to $P_4$ is

$$ \vec{v}_{34}=\left\langle\frac{y_3-y_2}{s_{23}},-\frac{x_3-x_2}{s_{23}}\right\rangle$$

or its negative (since the dot-product $\vec{v}_{34}\cdot\vec{v}_{23}=0 $). The vector equation of the line containing $P_3$ and $P_4$ is

$$ P=P_3+\vec{v}_{34}s $$

Since the distance from $P_3$ to $P_4$ is $s=s_{34}=s_{23}\tan(d_1)$ then

\begin{eqnarray}
P_4&=&P_3\pm\vec{v}_{34}s_{23}\tan(d_1)
\end{eqnarray}

Assuming that $P_4$ is on the same side of the line through $P_2$ and $P_3$ as is $P_1$, that will determine whether to use the plus or minus sign in the last equation.

Comment: I am unclear on the part where s = d23.  I would assume you need to know d1 using P1, P2, P3 so that you can calculate s.  If I understand your solution right you do not use P1 at all?  I have added another image as another example.  Thank you for the help, it is fun revisiting this.

Comment: My apologies, I somehow left out $\tan(d_1)$ from the equation. I also have changed the $d_{ij}$ notation to $s_{ij}$ notation for better consistency of notation.

Comment: Thank you so much for the help.  I have done an example and coded it in and it is working great except for the the determining the sign part.  I am unsure how to do that.  Looking into it.  Also d23 should be changed to s23 on the 4th line.

Comment: There are two possible choices for $P_4$. If you want the one on the same side of the line $P_2P_3$ as point $P_1$ you can try one of these [algorithms](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28555246/finding-out-if-two-points-are-on-the-same-side/28555608).